# How to exploit this simple Smart Contract?

Tags: security, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, exploit

I have been trying a lot of ways of exploiting this simple token contract written in Solidity for the Ethereum blockchain; yet, I am unable to successfully do so.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract SimpleToken{

mapping(address => uint) public balances;

function buyToken() payable public {
    balances[msg.sender]+=msg.value / 1 ether;
}

function sendToken(address _recipient, uint _amount) public {
    require(balances[msg.sender]!=0); // You must have some tokens.
    balances[msg.sender]-=_amount;
    balances[_recipient]+=_amount;
    }
}
```

I have been able to achieve such exploitation by sending transactions to the sendToken() function, but I am trying to write a contract that serves as the Exploit code for it.

Here is what I have tried:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

import "./vuln.sol";

contract Exploit {
    
    function buyPoisoned() payable public {
        SimpleToken t = new SimpleToken();
        t.buyToken{gas: 50000, value: 10}();
    }

    function exploit(address recpt, uint amount) public {
        SimpleToken t = new SimpleToken();
        t.sendToken{gas: 50000}(recpt, amount);
    }
}
```

I have also tried with prior versions of the Solidity compiler (0.4.2 to be more precise), and yet I was unable to succeed.

I do not know what I am missing to make it work.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Since the contract is compiled with Solidity 0.8, it seems to be currently unexploitable.

Solidity 0.8 introduced automatic exception on integer underflow/overflow, see the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.4/080-breaking-changes.html).

I run the source code through [mythril](https://github.com/ConsenSys/mythril/) and it didn't find any vulnerabilities either.

---

If it were compiled with v0.7.6 or older, it would be vulnerable to [integer underflow](https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-101) on the line `balances[msg.sender]-=_amount;`.

For example you have 100 tokens, and you want to send 200:

It would pass the `require()` check, and subtracted 200 (amount to send) from 100 (the actual balance), which would result in integer underflow:

- `msg.sender` would have 2^256 - 101 tokens (because 0-1 results in 2^256-1 in case of integer underflow)
- `_recipient` would have 200 tokens (the sent amount)

Comment: Great to know about underflow/overflow being checked by the EVM from v0.8 towards, somehow, the exercise was built for 0.4.2, I thought it would not matter that much, in that case I have tried making a delegatecall() to keep the changes in the vulnerable contract, but changes were not kept.

Comment: `delegatecall` uses context (storage and balance, except for the `msg` global variable) of the caller. So if the `Exploit` was the **target** of delegatecall, you could not update its storage.